# SQLite syntax - join data from 3 tables

Tags: sqlite

I have 3 sqlite tables:

table `inspections`, where `insp_id` is `primary key`

```
id | name         | deleted
------------------------------
I1 | Inspection A | (null)
I2 | Inspection B | (null)
I3 | Inspection C | 1
```

table `equip_insp`, where `equip_id, insp_id` are `primary keys`

```
equip_id | insp_id  | period  | period_type
--------------------------------------------
E1       | I1       | 1       | Y
E1       | I2       | 6       | M
E2       | I1       | 1       | M
```

table `equip_certif`, where `id` is `primary key`

```
id  | equip_id | insp_id | date       | certif_no | result | info
-------------------------------------------------------------------
C4  | E1      | I1       | 2015-02-01 | A-300     | Good   | (null)
C3  | E1      | I1       | 2015-02-01 | A-200     | Good   | (null)
C2  | E1      | I1       | 2015-01-10 | A-100     | Good   | (null)
C1  | E1      | I2       | 2015-01-06 | B-100     | Good   | (null)
```

All ID's are in fact numeric values, I use some letters just to be easy to connect them in between.

So, I would like help me with the Sqlite syntax that for item E1, display all the inspection defined (ascending), then if exist, to display the periodicity and then to display the latest certificate date (if there are 2 certificates in the same date, get the latest id), number and result that is not info

Result should be something like this:

```
id | name         | period | period_type | certif_no | date       | result
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
I1 | Inspection A | 1      | Y           | A-300     | 2015-02-01 | Good     
I2 | Inspection B | 6      | M           | B-100     | 2015-01-06 | Good
```

I've try this, but I'm not so sure that is correct.

```
SELECT inspections.id, inspections.name, equip_insp.period, equip_insp.period_type, equip_certif.certif_no, equip_certif.date AS certif_date, equip_certif.result
FROM inspections
LEFT JOIN equip_insp ON (inspections.id = equip_insp.insp_id AND equip_insp.equip_id = 'E1')
LEFT JOIN equip_certif ON (inspections.id = equip_certif.insp_id AND equip_certif.info IS NULL)
WHERE inspections.deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY equip_insp.insp_id
ORDER BY inspections.id, date(equip_certif.date) DESC, equip_certif.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with SQLite I get the solution by myself. So the answer is:

```
SELECT inspections.id, inspections.name, equip_insp.period, equip_insp.period_type, equip_certif.certif_no, equip_certif.date AS certif_date, equip_certif.result
FROM inspections
LEFT JOIN equip_insp ON (inspections.id = equip_insp.insp_id AND equip_insp.equip_id = 'E1')
LEFT JOIN equip_certif ON (inspections.id = equip_certif.insp_id AND equip_certif.equip_id = equip_insp.equip_id AND equip_certif.info IS NULL)
WHERE inspections.deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY inspections.id
ORDER BY inspections.id, date(equip_certif.date) DESC, equip_certif.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

To specifiy which row from a group gets returned, you must use MAX(); otherwise, you get some randrom row:

```
SELECT ..., MAX(equip_certif.date) AS certif_date, ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY equip_insp.insp_id
...
```

(This works only in SQLite 3.7.11 or later; in earlier version, the query would get more complex.)

Comment: do you have an idea about how to solve the case when 2 certificates have the same date, so I can get the one with the latest id introduced?